# How to prevent touch from a fragment affecting its parent activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, opacity

I have a fragment that is launched from an activity. Now I've noticed that when an empty area is touched, the parent activity is touched. Only area where there are buttons that are not affected. It acts as if it was tranparent.

Is there a way to prevent that?

Parent activity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@id/layout_dashboard_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/cardview_light_background">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@id/main_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@id/layout_dashboard_scroll_container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@id/dashboard_alert_section"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <include layout="@layout/dashboard_feature_tip_item" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@id/main_control_layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="611dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@id/layout_main"
                    style="@style/CardView.Dark"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/c_main_back_ground_color"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout_balance_check"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="120.0dip"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="6.0dip"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dashboard_feature_end_margin_usa"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dashboard_feature_start_margin_usa"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dashboard_feature_end_margin_usa"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dashboard_feature_start_margin_usa"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dashboard_feature_top_margin_usa"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:background="@color/battery_charging_icon_color"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:elevation="@dimen/dashboard_feature_bg_elevation"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat"
                        tools:targetApi="lollipop">

                        <include
                            layout="@layout/sub_layout_account_cb"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/view"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                            android:duplicateParentState="true" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout_balance_load"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="120.0dip"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="6.0dip"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dashboard_feature_end_margin_usa"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dashboard_feature_start_margin_usa"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dashboard_feature_end_margin_usa"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dashboard_feature_start_margin_usa"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:elevation="@dimen/dashboard_feature_bg_elevation"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        tools:targetApi="lollipop">

                        <include
                            layout="@layout/sub_layout_account_lb"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                            android:duplicateParentState="true" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout_credit_share"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="120.0dip"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="6.0dip"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dashboard_feature_end_margin_usa"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dashboard_feature_start_margin_usa"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dashboard_feature_end_margin_usa"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dashboard_feature_start_margin_usa"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:elevation="@dimen/dashboard_feature_bg_elevation"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        tools:targetApi="lollipop">

                        <include
                            layout="@layout/sub_layout_account_sc"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                            android:duplicateParentState="true" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout_credit_barrow"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="120.0dip"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="6.0dip"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dashboard_feature_end_margin_usa"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dashboard_feature_start_margin_usa"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dashboard_feature_end_margin_usa"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dashboard_feature_start_margin_usa"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:elevation="@dimen/dashboard_feature_bg_elevation"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        tools:targetApi="lollipop">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_borrow_credit"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_borrow_credit_warning"
                            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_borrow_credit_warning"
                            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
                            android:text="@string/borrow_credit"
                            android:textColor="@color/c_main_back_ground_color"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_borrow_credit_warning"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView3"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
                            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
                            android:background="@color/c_main_back_ground_color"
                            android:paddingEnd="5dip"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                            android:paddingRight="5dip"
                            android:paddingStart="5dip"
                            android:text="@string/borrow_credit_warning"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
                            android:textColor="?android:attr/editTextColor"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
                            android:contentDescription=""
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/engaging" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                            android:duplicateParentState="true" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dip"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:animationCache="true">

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:animationCache="true">

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/africell_cb_int"
    android:layout_width="410dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/textColorLinkInverse"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10.0dip"
    android:weightSum="1.0">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="332dp"
        android:layout_height="97dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
        android:text="@string/load_balance_dialog"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/action_button_color"
        android:clickable="false">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputField"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
            android:layout_width="322dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="@string/edit_text_hint"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text_color"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:maxLines="1" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.39"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/confirm"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.36"
            android:text="@string/confirm"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes for that you have to make your root view clickable. Just set property clickable true even no need to write empty `OnClickListener` for that.

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Your Fragment xml have root view with an id `africell_cb_int`. Make it clickable.

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:clickable="true"` for the root tag in your Fragment Xml layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true" />
```